# iOS - Sqlite read and write simultaneously

Tags: ios, database

In my application, I've two threads running. One will be querying the server and updates the database. Other thread will get the data and update the UI.
The issue is that when both read and write are calling database simultaneously one is failing.
the error is as follows:
**Error while creating SELECT c.id, c.address, c.type, e.id, e.name, e.logo, e.system, c.city FROM cashpoints c, entities e WHERE e.id = c.entity AND c.id = ?; => 'database is locked'**

Comment: you should use FMDatabase: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb to avoid thread sync errors with your SQLite DB

Comment: Just checking ... do you commit after updating your database ?

Comment: @meccan: I think for a few sql statements its waste to integrate a huge fmdb src.

Comment: @giorashc: I'm not commiting. But i think the error is due to simultaneous access of database.

Comment: @Satyamsvv but FMDatabase base automatic locking and thread synchronizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @meccan, the solution is to use FMDB or better go with core data.

Comment: Notably FMDatabaseQueue of FMDB.